# how can i add style to vue component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have this code. It is a component for a base64 file input. And it also supports drag and drop. I need styling for drag and drop. But it removes the style every time. After the render, style tag disappears and styles are not applied. How can I add style to this component?

Thank you.

```
Vue.component('file-base64', {
    template:`
        <div class="custom-file" style="padding:0;" @dragenter="ondragenter" @dragover="" @dragleave="ondragleave" @drop="ondrop">
            <input :id="inputid" class="custom-file-input" type="file" @change="onChange" :multiple="multiple" />
            <label :for="inputid" class="custom-file-label">{{label}}</label>
            <style>
                #{{inputid}} .fileuploaddrophover {height:auto; border:2px dotted gold;}
                #{{inputid}} .fileuploaddrophover > label {opacity: 0.5; filter:blue(5px);}
            </style>
        </div>
    `,
    data: function () {
        return {inputid:(function(){var x; do{x= "filebase64input"+Math.round(Math.random()*100000);} while(document.getElementById(x)) return x;})()};
    },
    props:{
        label:{type:String,default:"Drop or Choose file..."},
        multiple: {type: Boolean,default: false},
        done: {type: Function,default: () => {}}  
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(e){
            let files = e.target.files;  
            var allFiles = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                let file = files[i];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = () => {
                    let fileInfo = {name: file.name,type: file.type,size: file.size,base64: reader.result.split(',')[1],file: file};
                    allFiles.push(fileInfo);
                    if(allFiles.length == files.length){
                        if(this.multiple) this.done(allFiles);
                        else this.done(allFiles[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ondragenter : function (e) {
            $("#"+this.inputid).parent().addClass('fileuploaddrophover');
        },
        ondragleave : function (e) {
            $("#"+this.inputid).parent().removeClass('fileuploaddrophover');
        },
        ondrop : function (e) {
            $("#"+this.inputid).parent().removeClass('fileuploaddrophover');
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Why did you write that the styles disappeared? 
The problem is that on dev version they are working but on prod they don't? 
Describe a case further. Do you use webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way.

Since data is function it is called every time when an element is added.

```
data: function () {
    return {
        inputid:(function(){var x; do{x= "filebase64input"+Math.round(Math.random()*100000);} while(document.getElementById(x)) return x;})(),
        cssrules:(function(){
            var css = document.createElement("style");
            css.type = "text/css"; 
            css.innerHTML = `
                .fileuploaddrophover { height:auto; border:2px dotted gold; }
                .fileuploaddrophover > label {opacity: 0.5; filter:blue(5px); }
            `;
            document.body.appendChild(css);
        })(),
    };
},
```

It is definitely a hack but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The goal you are trying to achieve is to add style to the [global component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Global-Registration).
My advice is not to use this way.

Instead, you can just create [Single File Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) where you are able to declare all `template` `script` and `style` sections.

After this, you can just import it in the place where you create Vue application (in most cases it's `main.js`).

So, you will have your `FileBase64.vue` file.

And in `main.js` you will have:

```
import FileBase64 from './FileBase64.vue'
Vue.component('file-base64', FileBase64);
```

Comment: Can this work without webpack? I am not using webpack.

Comment: You can do it without webpack. Splitting the `.vue` file into three parts, html, js and css. But the most awesome thing in Vue is Single File Component, so I suggest you use it and there are some workarounds how to use it without webpack/gulp but it will be less convenient

Comment: @rturkek
was my answer useful for you?

Comment: I am looking for an answer for either using <style> in a global component or an example of how to move it to a single file component without webpack.

Comment: @rturkek as documentation says:
All of these are solved by single-file components with a .vue extension, made possible with build tools such as Webpack or Browserify.

So, I guess it's not possible without these tools